# How to start a IIS process with specific username & password

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, process, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to run an application from our internal website. When I use `Process.Start("notepad");` I can see that notepad process started in our web server with default identity mentioned in the app pool setting.

But I have to start the process with specific user name & password. So I have tried to run this line of code

```
string password = "XXXXX";
System.Security.SecureString securePwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    // Append the character to the password.
    securePwd.AppendChar(c);
}
Process.Start("notepad", "username", securePwd, "domain");
```

In this case I don't even see any notepad process started in the web server. The lines of code executing because when I pass wrong password I can see my webpage throwing error of "bad username or password".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your reply. Here I got the solution and now my process start with impersonated user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/aspnet/spawn-process-under-impersonated-user

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written looks fine to me. Perhaps the problem is

> I don't even see any notepad process

I would try the following

Capture the ID and write it out to the client e.g.

```
Process note = Process.Start("notepad", "username", securePwd, "domain");
Response.Write( note.ID ); //Or whatever mechanism you prefer.
```

Then log on to the server and with PowerShell query the process

e.g.

```
PS C:\> get-process notepad  | Select ProcessName, Id 
ProcessName                                                                  Id
-----------                                                                  --
notepad                                                                    5512
```

The Id should match what was written to the client

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have captured process ID and print it in label control. Every time I execute that process I can see a new process ID. But when I go to power shell and search for that process it gives me error " Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "notepad". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again."

Comment: @Pritam Karmakar. That's weird. That means that the process got created but was destroyed before the powershell call.

Comment: Its really very weird behavior. Is there any other way to run application with specific user name?