# Application launched from ASP.NET using Process.Start fails if user credentials are specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, process.start

I'm unable to use `Process.Start` to start a simple console application when I specify user credentials. It appears that the call to `Process.Start` tries to start the application, but the application immediately fails with an event log entry (see below). I'm running IIS 7.5/.NET 4.0 on a Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) machine. Application pool runs under ApplicationPoolIdentity and uses Integrated Mode. Web site is set to run under Full Trust.

To test, I created a simple console application, `ConsoleApplication1`, that simply writes "Hello World" to the console and appends the current date and time to a text file, just so I can see that the application executed. When I run the application from a button click in my ASP.NET app using the following code, I see a new value get written into my text file, as expected.

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\dump\test\ConsoleApplication1.exe");
}
```

When I try to specify a set of user credentials to run the application using the code below, nothing is written to my text file, and I see a message in the Event Viewer that states:

`Application popup: ConsoleApplication1.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.`

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\dump\test\ConsoleApplication1.exe",
        "myusername", CreatePassword("mypassword"), string.Empty);
}

private static SecureString CreatePassword(IEnumerable<char> password)
{
    var ss = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password)
        ss.AppendChar(c);
    return ss;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the authentication of the user credentials is working properly, because I get a `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password` error if I enter incorrect info.

I feel like I must be missing something simple, but can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Did you try passing the password in cleartext?

Comment: What do you mean? To set the password parameter in the call to Process.Start, you have to pass in an instance of SecureString.

Comment: Basically the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022408/how-to-start-a-iis-process-with-specific-username-password Hard to believe it's really not possible to do this with `Process.Start`.

Comment: The solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677874/starting-a-process-with-credentials-from-a-windows-service worked for me (same problem).